# Xamarin iOS Designer - Accessibility fields

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, accessibility

Does Xamarin.iOS integrated Designer (preferably Visual Studio, but I could use Xamarin Studio) support defining the AccessibilityIdentifier and/or AccessibilityLabel?
I don't want to use XCode's Interface Builder JUST for this...

Am I missing something? I'm using the latest stable version (Xamarin 3.11.1537.0 and Xamarin.iOS 9.0.1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this has been added to the Alpha Channel! Now "All accessibility properties are supported."

http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_5.10/xamarin.studio_5.10/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the AccessibilityIdentifier programatically, but I personally do not know of it being exposed anywhere via Xam's designer.

i.e.

[Setting the Accessibility ID Programatically](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/testcloud/set-accessibilityidentifier-ios/)

> The AccessibilityIdentifier is bound by modern versions of
>   Xamarin.iOS. In your C# code you may set the value like so:

```
view.AccessibilityIdentifier = "CreditCardTextField";
```

> The ViewDidLoad event is a logical place to set the
>   AccessibilityIdentifier property.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but I hate to do this since it can be done thru IB and ->should<- be done thru the Xamarin's Designer.

Comment: Same here :-/ but it works, if you find another way, let me know and/or just self-answer your question here

Comment: You could create a custom control that exposes AccessibilityIdentifier with another name thru a property that is visible on the designer. This way you could set it thru the Designer, but that's just awful... Xamarin should support it, that's the only way to use Xamarin's own UITests...

Comment: A hidden widget to set properties, did that a decade+ ago in C++ to give VB programmers access to non-expose win32 items... no thanks ;-)